# How to make rake task fall over if data is equal to something

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently looking for a way to make my whole rake task finish if something the column in the database starts with www.google.co.uk/

I've tried doing this

```
if ('row[14] LIKE ?', "http://www.google.co.uk/")
else
everything else in the rake task
```

Also, If the link is

http://www.google.co.uk/hgfadasdyfyasgfyregyfhsagtyfgtfae/fsafsasfs/sfaf/asfa/dd

Would this return true?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "LIKE" clause requires that you have wildcards in the test string, in the form of a "%" sign.  Eg

```
where(['row[14] LIKE ?', "http://www.google.co.uk%"])
```

In your case it's hard to advise exactly what the code should be, since there's no context or any other information about what you are actually   doing.  You seem to be trying to use an sql query fragment inside an "if" test which doesn't really make sense: you would do an if test on an object.

If you want to do a database search then use the syntax above.  If you have already loaded the record into a Rails object then you could test the string with a regex, eg

```
if url =~ /^http\:\/\/www\.google\.co\.uk/
```

BTW, this is the sort of thing that is super easy to google for, and it's better to do that before coming to stack overflow with a very simple question like this.

Comment: `SyntaxError: /Users/samroberts/Desktop/website/lib/tasks/load.rake:18: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'` Didn't work :(

Comment: ah, i was only focussed on the "like" syntax bug and didn't notice that the rest of your code doesn't make sense :) Will edit.